# How to adjust default sound settings in OSX for headphones

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, audio, headphones

Sometimes when I plug in my headphones, OSX will change the volume to halfway. This is too much. How can I make it so that when I plug in my headphones the volume is lower?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X uses the volume you set your headphones to when you last unplugged them (try for example plugging them in, muting the sound, and then plugging them out and - after a moment - back in: the sound should still be muted). So you will have to tune down your volume manually after plugging in to avoid hurting your ears.

Comment: Yes, I did notice this before. But for some reason sometimes it puts it in the middle even though I didn't put it there before.

Comment: Are you using iPhone/iPad headphones (the ones with a remote) by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm not using those.